# Netbeans theme colour setting

Tags: netbeans, colors, themes

How I can change the color of this label with options?

[image: blue color in dialogue]

Comment: It depends on your operating system; on linux, it furthermore depends on your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot explicitly change that electric blue font, but you can do it implicitly by changing the look and feel of the NetBeans IDE. This will not impact the color and font settings for the editing window itself, but almost everything else will be changed.

Your theme is specified in **Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Profile**, and you do not need to change that. Here's an example of how your screen shot looks using the **Darcula** theme:

[image: themeDarcula]

To modify the look and feel go to **Tools-> Options -> Appearance -> Look and Feel** and select an entry from the **Preferred look and feel** drop list:

[image: SetLookAndFeel]

After clicking the **OK** button NetBeans will restart using the new look and feel. You can then test to see if your new look and feel gives you a better font/background combination.

You cannot preview the look and feel change, so you may need to restart NetBeans a few times to find a look and feel that appeals to you. Shown below are a couple of screen shots after changing the look and feel to **Nimbus** and then **Dark Nimbus**, with **Darcula** retained for the editing window:

[image: Nimbus]

[image: DarkNimbus]

Alternatively, if you don't want to have a look and feel that differs from your theme, just use a different theme. There are plenty to choose from. For example:

- [NetBeans Themes](https://netbeansthemes.com/)
- [This site has over 90 themes](http://svenspruijt.nl/themebuilder/). Just click the **Theme** button to see the list and preview them.